# Best practice for preparation of front end content -iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, graphics, frontend

My client wants to know the best practice for creation of customized content for iPhone. For example if there are same style buttons with customized background and different titles say "Button to Submit" and "Button to Go Back" is it better to provide a general background image and change the title at runtime, or provide different images for different titles. Does apple provide any guidelines regarding the same? 
Also if I provide the title programmatically for different buttons how much customization is possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost impossible to answer without knowing more. As a rule of thumb, try to maintain the biggest flexibility by hardcoding as little as possible within the supplied graphics. However, that might collide with the designer's dream of customizing each and every pixel of a UI. One real-life-example would be a special font used for the button titles that is not available on the device itself, hence would need pre titles button bitmaps.

Comment: @Til it is possible to include fonts in the app, that are not available on the device and use them for labels, buttons etc (since iOS 3.2).

Comment: @phix23 yep, it is possible, but you need to license the typeface for embedding.

Comment: Thanks all for clarification, I would like to expand more. Currently I allocate a customized button with designated frame and in IB I choose the images for default and selected state. It gives the designer flexibility to customize the text on the button title as much as possible. The other option would be placing hardcoded text on the button programmatically and customizing the placement and size of the text. What would be the pros and cons of each option? Again thanks everyone for their input

Answer (score 0):

Place the text over the image, use localizations for any 'hard coded' text in your program.  Avoid hardcoding the text into the image.  It's hard to change later and it is language dependent.

NSLocalizedString(@"Submit item text", @"Submit");
You can use localization strings for many languages later and expand your audience.
I recommend doing this from day-one and maintaining this practice throughout your code even if you're sure you will never have a non-english speaking person use the program.

Answer (score 0):

My practice is to create a customized background and then use it with different titles. This works very well, since UIButton is meant to be customized.

When the titles have different length, you can automatically stretch the background image to fit.

Example:

```
// button-bg.png has size 30x60
UIImage* image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:0];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can furthermore add an image in the foreground and customize the font, color and relative position of the title for different states.